# Is it possible to create a custom button in magento 2 to send email?

Tags: email

i have a doubt that is it possible to create a custom button in magento 2 to send email?

i have to create one custom button in pdp page and if i click the button it should send me the email. can we do that and if so how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. In fact it's built in.

Go to: Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Email to a friend

It's all in there.

It won't look how you want it to look, but once you've enabled it (and tested it) you can just style it up with CSS.

Good luck!

[image]